# ggpredict random intercept logistic model: What does `ggpredict` actually predict? What does the manual mean by "population-level"?

Tags: r, mixed-model, predictive-models

In R, function `ggpredict` can be used to generate model-predicted values for a random-effect model, like a random intercept logistic regression model. For such model, `ggpredict` offers two possibilities, `type="fixed"` and `type="random"`. About the default `type="fixed"`, the manual says:

> Predicted values are conditioned on the fixed effects or conditional model only (for mixed models: predicted values are on the population-level and confidence intervals are returned).

My question is about the last part of the above sentence, between the brackets: "on the population-level" sounds like "population averaged predictions", like gee-models produce. However, using gee (with an exchangeable correlation structure) to estimate my logistic model, leads to different predicted probabilities than those obtained from `ggpredict`. Furthermore, the predicted probabilities obtained with `ggpredict` are highly similar (up to 4 or 5 decimals) to those calculated "by hand" (based on results of `glmer` in R), for a respondent having an average intercept. So the predicted probabilities from `ggpredict` seem to be subject-specific rather than population-averaged. Do you have an idea what `ggpredict` actually does predict, or what the manual may mean with "population-level"?